# Change JAR File after deployed WAR on Tomcat possible?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war

I have a war file deployed to my tomcat server. Tomcat unpacks the war file and I can access the WEB-INF/lib folder.

There is a newer version of somelib.jar in WEB-INF/lib. I want to upgrade this without recompiling the war file.

Can I change somelib.jar in WEB-INF/lib for a version upgrade without any consequenses? Or does my servlet crahes after restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can *theoretically*. You would have to restart Tomcat or stop/start the application in Tomcat. Note that a WAR is like a ZIP file, you can unpack it, replace the JAR file and zip it again.

Note that I would not recommend to simply replace a JAR in a WAR. This could have bad consequences. You should first test the change (is it already tested?). The new JAR could introduce some incompatible changes. The best practice would be also to have a configuration management, so that you can anytime later get or build again the WAR you deployed.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change just a jar file inside WEB-INF/lib, but you will have to restart your tomcat.

Comment: is there any alternative way to replace jar in WEB-INF/lib without restarting tomcat?

Comment: @gaurav Actually, you could use tomcat manager console - to undeploy old war and deploy a new one, without restarting tomcat as pointed out in other answer.

Comment: In this case, it would be easier to generate jar using maven and replace it in WEB-INF/lib by restarting tomcat instead of generating new WAR and doing deploy and un-deploy....

Answer (score 2):

Try to redeploy  the war file using the tomcat manager console. There you have option to start/stop deployed web application.